# jupyter render matplotlib charts individually within python loop

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter

I have a function which is generating text output and matplotlib chart output.

```
def myfunction(input):
    for x in input:
        print('some text')
        fig = thing.as_pyplot_figure()
        print (fig)
```

the output in jupyter notebook produces the print text statements in sequence, then the printed pyplot charts in sequence. Is there any way to print text 1, chart 1, text2, chart 2, etc?